# Different URLs with duplicate content

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content

A law firm has decided to launch multiple websites with the idea of using keywords in the URL (i.e. `personalinjurylawyers.com`, `businesslaw.com`, etc. ) as well as one for their firm name. Even though the content for each site will be different depending on practice area, they will come from the same host/IP and will have some duplicate content (contact info, firm name, etc.) as well as layout. Will this be penalized by Google in terms of search rankings?

Comment: See also: [The SEO benefit of breaking up content onto different websites](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/the-seo-benefit-of-breaking-up-content-onto-different-websites)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on percentage of duplicate content. If the majority of pages content of different websites is unique, I don't think Google will penalize them in terms of SEO . A lot of websites have duplicate content for generic pages like terms and conditions, contacts, etc. and aren't penalized for duplicate content by Google.