# SEO and multiple simple websites

Tags: seo, link-building, site-structure

From a **SEO point of view**, which one is "better" for a not so little company: **Having one huge site** containing everything regarding the company **or having multiple one?** I think one site is better, because it is easier to optimize and advertise, but I just started working in a company, where we have multiple simple websites (almost single page) to handle offer requests. My boss don't want this site structure changed. (These sites have no connection at all, but the first thing I would do is link them and by linking I mean adding a page where there are links to the other pages).

It is easier to explain through an example. We have domains structured like this (not the real ones):

- forkliftparts.com : for forklift parts
- forkliftseat.com : for ordering seats
- forklifttire.com : handling orders regarding tires
- forkliftbattery.com : and for batteries
- ...

The sites are basically the same, with a little color difference. Should I start advertising the pages separately? What could I do to improve the standing in search engines? The sites are built with WordPress and with the use of SEO plugins, so I am more interested in **off-site seo**.

Comment: Hi @pokemarine there are many answers and questions regarding sub folders, sub domains, multiple domains vs one domain on Pro Webmasters already. Also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/the-seo-benefit-of-breaking-up-content-onto-different-websites/7964#7964 may interest you.

Comment: You should change the referenced duplicate to the question you linked in your comment I think.